# Change cell color based on the greater value between two columns - Excel 2010

Tags: excel, ms-office, excel-2010, office-2010

Look, the scenario is simple! I have a sheet with two columns. These columns have integers.

What I need to do is compare each value from column A with its respective value on columns B and then, change the color of the cell which contains the greater value.

Please, note that I need to do this rule to each line.

Answer (score 2):

Click on cell A1, click on conditional formatting -> New Rule -> Use a formula which cell to format, and enter the following:

=$A1>$B1

Format the background colour to what you would like. Then copy cell A1 and highlight all of column A. Do a paste special and only copy the format.

Do the same with column B but use following formula:

=$B1>$A1

Hope this helped.

Comment: Worked in one cell, but when I try to do a special copy, Excel just paste de same formula.

When I paste, each cell has the same initial formula. All the A cells contains =$A1>$B1 and B cells contains =$B1>$A1

I just need to paste and automatically put the respective cell ID in  the formula.

Comment: Rodrigo, double check your formula - it sounds like you are using $A$1>$B$1 and not $A1>$B2.

Comment: Yes, actually, the problem was the $. I was forced to remove all the $. Now it works! Thanks for your support! =)